# Get the next date by specifying the day of week

Tags: java, android, date

I need to use calendar to do this approach, basicly i get the specific day of week (1,2,3) each int represents a day of week(Monday,Tuesday) not in this order, but the logic is this.

What i need is to get the date of the next day of week, imagine today is Monday, and the user select Wednsesday, i need to get the date of the next Wednesday.

My logic is this at the moment:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dayOfWeek);
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                dateMatch = calendar.getTime();
```

day of week is passed from a slidePicker, and represents the specific day of week, this DAY_OF_WEEK doesn't work, if i put Wednseday he gives me 6

Comment: After selecting date add 7 days in calendar object and after then get the dayofweek calendar

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although your question text only says to find next `dayOfWeek`, your code also includes a time of day, in the form of `hour` and `minute`.

Assuming you want the first future occurrence of that combination, i.e. `dayOfWeek`, `hour`, and `minute`, that means that if today is that `dayOfWeek`, you either want today if time of day is later than now, or next week if time of day is earlier than now.

You can do that like this:

```
int dayOfWeek = Calendar.WEDNESDAY;
int hour      = 10; // 10 AM
int minute    = 0;

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // Today, now
if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != dayOfWeek) {
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, (dayOfWeek + 7 - cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)) % 7);
} else {
    int minOfDay = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60 + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    if (minOfDay >= hour * 60 + minute)
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7); // Bump to next week
}
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

System.out.println(cal.getTime()); // Prints: Wed May 10 10:00:00 EDT 2017
```

Comment: awesome, but there is something that confuses me, you don't set the day you don't need to do that?

Comment: because the day can not be today + 7 days, the day is choosed by the user, today is monday, but he can choose wednesday

Comment: @AntonioCosta Yes, and WEDNESDAY (4) - MONDAY (2) = 2, and today (which is a Monday) + 2 days = Wednesday, May 10. If today had been THURSDAY (5), then WEDNESDAY (4) - THURSDAY (5) + 7 = 6, and Thursday, May 11 + 6 days = Wednesday, May 17. The code doesn't *set* the day-of-week, but calculates how many days to add to the current date to get to that day-of-week.

Comment: damn that was really smart, what an awesome answer dude, did you implement by your own or adapted, because i never find this kind of solutions, ty very much !:D

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

To get the next Wednesday after today, or stick with today’s date if already a Wednesday.

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) )
    .with( TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY )  )
```

## java.time

Use modern *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old legacy date-time classes such as `Calendar`.

Use `DayOfWeek` enum objects to represent Monday-Sunday. Use smart objects rather than dumb integers to represent your day-of-week intention. Makes your code more self-documenting, ensures valid values, and provides type-safety.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) implementation such as [`TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#nextOrSame-java.time.DayOfWeek-) to move to another date.

```
TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY ) ;
LocalDate nextOrSameWednesday = today.with( ta ) ;
```

If working with moments, use `ZonedDateTime` class rather than the awful `Calendar` class. Some idea as above, let the [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) do the heavy-lifting. But keep in mind that **the time-of-day may be altered** if that time-of-day is invalid for that new date such as during a [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) cut-over.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtSameOrNextWednesday = zdt.with( ta ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).